# TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined - Find The Parity Outlier

Tags: javascript, concatenation

[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
Should return: 11 (the only odd number)
[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
Should return: 160 (the only even number)

Above are Javascript coding question and here is my answer. But I found the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined"

Please help me what I was wrong.
Thank you!

```
function findOutlier(arr){
  //your code here
  var even,odd = 0;
  var evenArr, oddArr = [];

  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
      evenArr = evenArr.concat(arr[i]);
      // console.log(evenArr);
     } else {
      oddArr = oddArr.concat(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  if (evenArr.length > oddArr.length) {
    return oddArr[0];
  } else {
    return evenArr[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: You meant to use `var evenArr = [], oddArr = [];`

Answer (score 1):

```
  var evenArr, oddArr = [];
```

This initialized `oddArr` to an empty array, but does not initialize `evenArr`.

You need to set the variable to an array before you can call methods on it.